# Word or phrase for a story that takes place over several years

Tags: single-word-requests

What word or phrase should be used to describe a story that takes place over a long period of time (e.g. a few years, a few decades, etc.)?

For example, Gabriel García Márquez's famous novel *One Hundred Years of Solitude* takes place over seven generations of the Buendía family. What word or phrase could be used to describe the story?

> *One Hundred Years of Solitude* is a **____**, that is, it occurs over a long period of time.

Comment: How about [epic?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/epic). Seems to cover part of it.

Answer (score 4):

A  [Saga](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Saga):

> - Also called *saga novel*,  a form of novel that chronicles the members or generations of a family or social group.
> - (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) 
>     a series of events or a story stretching over a long period.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Saga

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a noun that accurately describes what you are asking for (epic and saga, for example, describe a lot more than the time-frame of the work they describe). However, the adjective 'multi-generational' might be what you're looking for, as in "One Hundred Years of Solitude is a multi-generational novel.

Comment: Actually a 'saga novel' is a multigenerational novel by definition! :)

Answer (score 0):

'Chronicle drama'--a story taking place over several or many years (Merriam-Webster). Usually, when discussing a chronicle drama such as a play, a novel or a tv mini-series, the word 'drama' is dropped. The drama is simply referred to as a 'chronicle'.